# Geospatial Sharding in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, sharding

What are some good ways to shard geospatial indexes? Or would it be efficient to store them into one large collection? I know MongoDB supports sharding based on a specified shard key which in turn scales pretty good if you which part of the data to shard. But I can't seem to wrap my head around how to shard geospatial indexes?